# Is there a method to obtain the value of an Android string resource except getString(R.string.idString) with Java language?

Tags: java, android, string

I need to use string resources in a common java class; I need to obtain their values by R.string.idstring which gives me an integer number and not the string value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a constructor in your java class and assign the `Context` as a parameter to it like this :

```
public class MyClass{

    MyClass(Context context){
        String idString = context.getString(R.string.idString);
    }
```

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: Thank you @mohammadReza Abiri, it works

Comment: Glad your problem is fixed!